# Indexing in Hibernate Search not working properly

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm trying to integrate Hibernate Search to my backend, but I can't make it work as I would like it to.

My intention is to retrieve all the following `model.Course` tuples only with the token "java":

[image]
[image: My model.Course table]

Currently, I'm only getting the `model.Course` with `id` = 26. That means Lucene is working, but I don't know how to create the query needed to perform the operation I want.

This is my `CourseService` code:

```
private Session session;
private FullTextSession fts;

public CourseService(){
    SessionFactory sf = SessionFactoryManager.getInstance(); // Singleton
    this.session  = sf.openSession();
    this.fts = Search.getFullTextSession(this.session);
}

public List<Course> searchCourses(String token) {

    try {
        this.fts.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Transaction tx = this.fts.beginTransaction();

    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = this.fts.getSearchFactory()
                                        .buildQueryBuilder()
                                        .forEntity(Course.class)
                                        .get();

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = queryBuilder.simpleQueryString()
                                                       .onField("description").andField("name")
                                                       .matching(token)
                                                       .createQuery();

    org.hibernate.query.Query hibQuery = fts.createFullTextQuery(query, Course.class);

    List result = hibQuery.getResultList();

    tx.commit();

    return result;
}
```

This is my `model.Course` code:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Course implements Comparable<Course>{

@Id
@DocumentId
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Field (termVector = TermVector.YES)
private String name;

@Field
private String description;

/*...*/

 protected Course(String name, String description, ...) {
    /*...*/
}
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** I initially thought it was a problem with the query, but it's actually an indexing problem.

[image: Here's a screenshot of my index's state (using Luke)]

I don't know how to solve this type of problem. I'm hearing suggestions. Details:

- I'm using a singleton for `SessionFactory` (I wasn't before the edit)
- I'm using `org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.8.2.Final`
- I'm using HSQLdb 2.4.0
- The rest of hibernate is working perfectly (CRUD operations)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an analysis issue, e.g. the analyzer chosen not splitting the field in tokens.

What is a bit weird is that the default analyzer (the StandardAnalyzer) split the field in tokens so it should work out of the box.

Have you set a different default analyzer (the KeywordAnalyzer for instance)?

Comment: No, I only have `<property name="hhibernate.search.analyzer">org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer</property>` specified in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` .

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo but you have 2 `h` at `hhibernate`. Anyway, it's supposed to be the default so it should work anyway. Could you try to get the @Field annotations to `@Field(analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = StandardAnalyzer.class)` so that we can rule out this issue?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Fixed that and added `@Field(analyzer = ...)` but it's still not working.

Comment: There's something wrong with your setup. I reproduced your case here: https://github.com/gsmet/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/so-50182085/search/hibernate-search-lucene and more specifically here: https://github.com/gsmet/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/so-50182085/search/hibernate-search-lucene/src/test/java/org/hibernate/search/bugs/YourTestCase.java#L27 and it works as expected. Hard to say what you're doing wrong though. Wondering if you are indexing the correct data.

Comment: Thanks for your code, I'm still trying to solve this problem. [Here](https://gist.github.com/lautaropaske/41ae23930cad774c9520d95b82538685) is a simplified version of my project with the 5 files involved in this problem, if you want to take a look at it. I also believe it's an indexing problem.

Comment: Could it be that I'm not using a singleton for Sessions? I have multiple SessionFactory's, one for each service.

Comment: Yes, you should have only one `SessionFactory`.

Comment: I edited the question, and updated my code. Still no results.